# Electronic configuration

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

In chemistry  the lithium  electronic configuration is

$$1s^22s^1 \, .$$

Can we prove this using approximation method like perturbation theory that this the ground state and not for example $1s^22p^1$?

Answer (score 1):

> In chemistry the lithium electronic configuration is given by
>   $1s^2\,2s^1$. Can we proof this using approximation method like
>   perturbation theory that this the ground state and not for example
>   $1s^2\,2p^1$ ?

Actually $1s^2\,2p^1$ exists at a higher energy, in all alkali metals
(with different $n$, of course). The absorption line 
$$n\,s \to n\,p$$
is the strongest one in the absorption spectrum. It's the yellow line
in sodium, red in Lithium, purple in Potassium, and so on.

In Hydrogen levels with the same $n$ and different $l$'s are (almost)
degenerate (same energy). Alkali atoms instead show a marked breaking
of degeneration. A qualitative explanation can easily be given in QM.

In an alkali atom with $N$ electrons $N-1$ of them assume the
configuration of a noble gas, a so-called closed shell, with a charge
distribution rather compact and spherically symmetric. They almost
completely screen the nuclear charge, leaving outside the shell the
electric field of a single positive charge $+e$. So the remaining
electron feels a quasi-Coulomb potential and its stationary states are
quite similar to Hydrogen orbitals.

This is why levels of alkali metals are rather alike those of
Hydrogen. Alike, but not equal. In fact last electron's orbitals (wavefunctions) are spread on a wide range of distances from
nucleus, thus "penetrating" (more or less) the closed shell. A
penetrating orbital feels a greater charge and this lowers its energy.

On the other hand, degree of penetration depends on angular momentum
($l$ quantum number): $s$-orbitals are the most penetrating, then
$p$-orbitals, and so on. This is why $ns$ has a lower energy than
$np$, this lower than $nd$ ...

Sure this is a theoretical argument, but it agrees so satisfactorily
with observed spectra that we may confidently assume it's describing
the real status of things. Of course accurate computations are
possible, giving a more detailed account of the structure of these and
other atoms.